# Как сделать код который запрашивает права администартора и проверяет дал ли их пользовать?

Tags: c#

Именно кодом запросить права админа, а не через manifest.

Comment: запросить права для чего?

Comment: я хочу запустить другое приложение, но оно требует права админа.

Comment: как ты запускаешь сейчас это приложение?

Comment: Procces.Start()

Comment: мне нужно сделать запрос прав админа, если пользователь дал, то запускает, если нет, просто дальше идёт работа.

Comment: добавь пример своего кода в вопрос. И стоит перефразировать вопрос на что-то вроде: как запустить другое приложение от имени администратора

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/133500/12888024

Comment: попробую щас, сек.

Comment: @aepot, напишешь ответ? :)

Comment: нет, не получилось, щас попробую сказать, точно что требуется. Нужно кодом сделать запрос прав админа, если права дали, то запустить, если нет, то продолжить выполнение кода.

Comment: Ребят, такой себе ответ. Я, конечно, понимаю, может человеку этого будет достаточно, но как быть, например, если запускается программа, но в ней пользователь выбирает директорию, которая нужна для работы программы, но она требует повышение прав до админа? Нам надо это проверить и выдать запрос на повышение. Так, например делают некоторые установщики софта. Так что, как по мне вопрос весьма интересный и не стоит его переделывать в "как запустить другое приложение от имени администратора", ибо это совершенно меняет его суть.

Comment: всё решил, я просто там ошибся в одном моменте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, но похоже суть вопроса именно в том, чтобы запустить приложение от имени администратора :) Ты можешь задать свой вопрос о повышении прав отдельно

Comment: @Grundy я не шарю в этой теме, я просто погуглил.

Comment: @aepot, можешь перевести ответ по ссылке и разобраться заодно :)

Comment: @Grundy там 5 ответов, я не знаю, какой из них лучше. Путь это лучше сделает тот, кому не лень. Я только за! :)

Comment: Решение для данного вопроса : https://stackoverflow.com/a/133500/12888024